# Computer (usually) requires RAM configuration to be changed for it to POST

Tags: boot, memory, ssd

**The problem**: About a week after installing a new 2.5" SSD, my computer would light up and all fans would spin, but no video output would show and the USB would not get powered. The first thing I tried was troubleshooting the RAM. I removed one of the two sticks and it booted up fine. However, the next time I went to turn it on it went back to doing what it originally did. I put the RAM back in that I thought was faulty and it booted up fine. The next time I went to boot, it was the same problem again, until I removed one stick of RAM. This has gone on and on for about a week now, as long as I change the RAM it boots fine. It usually requires the change after every successful boot, but a few times it has worked for multiple times before requiring a change.

**What I've tried**:

- Both sticks of RAM behave the same way.
- Tried disconnecting each of the storage drives, including the M.2.
- Tried removing the GPU.
- Tried disconnecting all USB devices.
- Ran Windows Memory diagnostics with no errors found
- It has only been a problem when the computer is actually off, I haven't had any issues when restarting

**System specs**:

- 2x Windows 10 Pro 64bit 20H2 (Dual booting)
- i5 4690
- Gigabyte GA-Z97X-UD3h-BK
- 2x Kingston HyperX 8GB 1866mhz
- Asus Strix GTX 970
- 1TB WD Black SN750 NVME
- 1TB WD Blue 2.5" SSD (Boot drive #1)
- 250GB Kingston 2.5" SSD (Boot drive #2)
- 2TB Seagate 3.5" HDD
- Corsair CS850M Bronze PSU

**Update**: It failed to boot this morning, so I left the PSU turned off for about 12 minutes. Afterwards it spun up, but died about 5 seconds later. After that it restarted itself and made it to the Gigabyte screen before dying again. It did that once more before I turned the PSU off, removed a DIMM and it booted up fine after that. I've also added the PSU to the spec list.

Comment: Please add another diagnostic step: Next time the computer does not boot, just switch it off, remove power for one minute mninimum, then reapply power and retry booting. Post results with your question. The rationale behind this: Maybe it is not canhing the RAM configiration, that fixes it, but the complete power off that comes with it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try the next time it happens

Comment: Pull out and reseat everything.. wiggle and push.. that is what I would do.  Also, make sure you blow out the case.